# HOw to hide and Show ag-grid columns based on Header name rather than field name

Tags: angular7, ag-grid, show-hide

I am trying to hide/show column based on headername using ag-grid. As you can see below, I have used setColumnsVisible to achieve the same. But I need to this based on headername amd not field.

```
{ headerName: 'Rating Name', field: 'newRatingName', filter: true}
this.gridColumnApi.setColumnsVisible(['newRatingName', 'newRatingReleaseDate'], false);true }
```

Is some other way to achieve it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have access to the `columnApi`, then I'd suggest you get the column using the `columnApi` and the `headerName`, and then use that to set the visibility.

For example:

```
const ratingNameColumn = this.gridColumnApi.getAllColumns().find(x => x.colDef.headerName == 'Rating Name');

this.gridColumnApi.setColumnVisible(ratingNameColumn, false);
```

[Here's](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ag-grid-angular-hello-world-w6inan) a StackBlitz for you.

Answer (score 0):

You can use hide property in the column definition to conditionally hide your column. This is a boolean property that can be set to true/false. For example:

```
{ headerName: 'Rating Name', 
  field: 'newRatingName', 
  filter: true,
  hide: this.shouldHide(),
}
shouldHide = () => (true);
```